# Cannot update the row in mysql via php

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to update a row in table  [showtable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3maX.png)

[Bugupdate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw1G2.png)
By using the php code below, binding a bugID to a SQL UPDATE statement to update the row I want to but it doesn't seem to work, is it the problem lie in my SQL statement ?

```
 $id = $_GET['update'];
 $games = htmlentities($_POST['games']);
        $version = htmlentities($_POST['version']);
        $platform = htmlentities($_POST['platform']);
        $frequency = htmlentities($_POST['frequency']);
        $proposal = htmlentities($_POST['proposal']);
        $SQLstring2 = "UPDATE " .$TableName. " SET Game=?,Version=?,Platform=?,Frequency=?,Proposed solution=? WHERE BugID= " .$id;
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($DBconnect, $SQLstring2)) {

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'sssss', $games, $version, $platform, $frequency, $proposal);
            $QueryResult2 = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            if ($QueryResult2 === FALSE) {
                echo "<p>Unable to execute the query.</p>"
                . "<p>Error code "
                . mysqli_errno($DBconnect)
                . ": "
                . mysqli_error($DBconnect)
                . "</p>";
            } else {
                echo "<h1> Thank you for your contribution";
            }
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }



        mysqli_close($DBconnect);
```

Comment: The issue is highly likely to be here: `Proposed solution=?` Field names are not allowed to have spaces; double check your column names.

Comment: you already have a `if($stmt...` but no `else`. That would have been the right place to show an error message (gotten from mysqli_error).

Comment: Oh yes, I just realized that, but the code still doesn't work

Comment: post your table schema

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to rename `Proposed solution` column to `Proposed_solution` and adapte the sql query like this :

```
$SQLstring2 = "UPDATE " .$TableName. " SET Game=?,Version=?, Platform=?, Frequency=?, Proposed_solution=? WHERE BugID= " .$id;
```